# Grails - DB migration for Quartz plug-in persistence

Tags: grails, quartz-scheduler, dbmigrate

We would like to use the Quartz plug-in persistent mode for working in a cluster.  Our DB schema is maintained using the DB-migration plug-in, and therefore we can not use the provided SQL script for updating the DB.

Is there a db-migration script (i.e. - a Groovy file) that creates the tables, that we can use? Can someone that managed to run the migration share one with us?

Alternatively - is there another way to create the tables, when working in DB migration mode?
Thanks

Comment: I don't know what the Quartz plug-in does (I'm guessing it adds some columns to the tables?), but I still don't quite understand your problem. The way the plugin works it generates a delta for you and applies it when you restart your application. Could you perhaps elaborate a bit?

Comment: The plug-in enables creating jobs, which are run at specific intervals, time, etc. The jobs can be either kept in memory (which is what we use so far), or in a DB (which is what we want to achieve, to enable running the job on a single server each time). The challenge is creating the DB tables for the plug-in. We use the DB migration capability of grails, which creates a tables using Liquibase syntax. Converting the Quartz tables creation script to DB migration format is not trivial, and I was wondering if someone has done it.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe instead of trying to convert the scripts you could use them directly by either considering this: http://www.liquibase.org/manual/formatted_sql_changelogs or this:http://www.liquibase.org/manual/custom_sql_file.  I think you can use liquibase's include tag with the sql change log.  Basically just copy and paste the contents and run them using one of the 2 methods I listed above.  If you use the second method, maybe you don't need to copy and paste anything and just directly reference it?

Comment: mingus5000 is correct in how to achieve this if you are limited to one database platform.  user964797 should accept this answer.